# How can I create unit test for void method with try...catch inside?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, void

I create simple service for example:

```
public class MyService {

    public void process() {

        try {
            CustomerMessagesService customerMessagesService = new CustomerMessagesService();
            String message = customerMessagesService.getMessage();

            // another logic which can throw an exception                

            SpamCenterService spamCenterService = new SpamCenterService();
            spamCenterService.sendAdvertise(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This service calls from **Scheduler** each 1 second.

`customerMessagesService` return message with an advertisement text or throw an exception if this message contains illegal text. If `customerMessagesService` return success text - it to send to `spamCenterService` and if `customerMessagesService` throw an exception - it exception just logged. There is another logic which can throw exception between calls of these services. This exception logs too.

Now I want to create a **unit test** for this method. But I don't understand how to test the `void` method with `try..catch` block.

I create this:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myService = new MyService();
    }

    @Test
    public void process() {
        myService.process();
    }
}
```

But it is always a success because the process method doesn't throw exceptions.
How can I test this method?

**EDIT**

I find one solution but I am not sure about it.

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

```
    public void process() {
        try {
           doIt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doIt() throws Exception {
      CustomerMessagesService customerMessagesService = new CustomerMessagesService();
            String message = customerMessagesService.getMessage();

            // another logic which can throw an exception                

            SpamCenterService spamCenterService = new SpamCenterService();
            spamCenterService.sendAdvertise(message);
    }
}
```

And test `doIt()` method in `MyServiceImpl`.

Comment: You should check the externally observable behaviour (ie: did `spamCenterService.sendAdvertise` get called when you expect, and maybe that it doesn't get called when you expect it to not get called).

Comment: I would change `MyService` to use inversion of control. Get some dependency injection framework, inject `CustomerMessagesService` and `SpamCenterService` and the use mocks in your test to control the behaviour.

Comment: you can't, the way it looks to me. if your services were declared on class level (as they probably should have been), you could have mocked them, and verified they were called correctly

Comment: What do you want to test? If you pass in the two services to the process method you could mock them and control what happens giving you different code paths.

Comment: @ cmoetzing I have it in the real project. How can it help me?

Comment: In other words - how can I understand that test of void method pass if this method doesn't throw exceptions? I haven't  `assertsEquals`, `assertTrue` and etc.

Comment: Change the method. Move the core of it in another method and have the catch logic a level above it, then test the core method which throws uncatched. Thats a pretty common issue with testing, you need to mock and create a better modular architecture. For example a method that reads in a file and changes stuff, hard to test. Change the method to accept and return String instead and create a method around it that does the file IO, then you can test the core method easily.

Comment: @ip696 You could use Mockito to [verify](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify) the mocked instances where called.

Answer (score 2):

In short do the following:

- Move object creation out of your method
- Create mocks (with e.g. Mockito) and inject those
- verify that the mocks were used as expected

A concrete example below:

```
public class MyService {

    private CustomerMessagesService customerMessagesService;
    private SpamCenterService spamCenterService;

    //inject dependencies
    public MyService(CustomerMessagesService customerMessagesService, SpamCenterService spamCenterService) {
        this.customerMessagesService = customerMessagesService;
        this.spamCenterService = spamCenterService;
    }

    public void process() {
        try {
            String message = customerMessagesService.getMessage();

            // another logic which can throw an exception

            spamCenterService.sendAdvertise(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class MyServiceTest {

    private MyService myService;
    // mock dependencies with Mockito
    private CustomerMessagesService customerMessagesService = Mockito.mock(CustomerMessagesService.class);
    private SpamCenterService spamCenterService = Mockito.mock(SpamCenterService.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myService = new MyService(customerMessagesService, spamCenterService);
    }

    @Test
    public void process() {
        myService.process();

        Mockito.verify(customerMessagesService).getMessage();
        ArgumentCaptor<String> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(spamCenterService).sendAdvertise(messageCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(messageCaptor.getValue(), is(nullValue()));
    }

    @Test
    public void processWithSpecificCustomerMessageServiceBehaviour() {
        Mockito.given(customerMessagesService.getMessage()).willReturn("expectedString");

        myService.process();

        ArgumentCaptor<String> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(spamCenterService).sendAdvertise(messageCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(messageCaptor.getValue(), is("expectedString"));
    }

    @Test
    public void processCatchExceptions() {
        Mockito.given(customerMessagesService.getMessage()).willThrow(new Exception("Bad message"));

        myService.process();

        // if exception is thrown then the code should not reach spamCenterService.sendAdvertise()
        Mockito.verify(spamCenterService, Mockito.never()).sendAdvertise(Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

Note that you can also setup mocks to throw specific exceptions or return specific values so that you can test all possible scenarios.